# How to get local timezone in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime, date, time, timezone

I'm using the `date("D, m/d/Y h:i:s A T")` function call to get current date time but returned time is different to the time I get when I make date in linux bash command (local time is in **CST** and php date function returns time in **UTC**). I've tried using `$timezone = @system("date +%Z",$retval);` to get timezone in an attempt to set local timezone using `date_default_timezone_set()` function. But **CST** seems not a valid timezone_identifier.

In short, I just need to get the same date and time as local datetime.

Comment: Again, please stop signing your posts.

Comment: Ok. I didn't know it was forbidden.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a timezone from http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

So, for CST use:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");
```

If you only have the timezone abbreviation and not the timezone id then use:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set(timezone_name_from_abbr("CST"));
```

Comment: +1 for being first. Note that the user may not be *Chicago*. Although indeed CT, it's best to use your specific locale.

Comment: the issue is I need it done programmatically so I can't go and copy the exact valid timezone_identifier each time I need it. The only value I have is CST or UTC and so on...

Comment: @StephaneKouakou I've added sample code for when you only have the timezone abbreviation

Comment: I think I've found a better function: timezone_name_from_abbr()

Comment: if you want to grab the default from *nix server, timezone_name_from_abbr(exec('date +%Z')) saves you from having a static entry

Answer (score 2):

Although the system and PHP *should* be on the same timezone, read the docs for [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://php.net/date_default_timezone_set) to set the timezone manually.

Note that CST is **not** a valid timezone setting. Find a [valid timezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php) for your location.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a better function: `timezone_name_from_abbr()`

Comment: If this turned out to be the correct answer, please mark it as correct.